# How to set timeout for login query of Parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, parse-platform

Is there any way to set timeout for login API of Parse SDK?

```
//Want to stop long-time login query
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground: ...

}];
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://www.parse.com/questions/ios-sdk-when-pfquery-find-timeout-is-very-very-long-waiting-time-how-can-i-set-timeout-value), you cannot set your own timeout.

In addition to that, [this post](https://parse.com/questions/is-there-an-api-timeout--2) says that the default timeout is 30 seconds.

I see nothing in the Parse documentation that indicates you can set your own, unfortunately.

Comment: I can stop PFQuery by using timer to cancel request but same can't stop query related to PFUser.

Answer (score 0):

The request timeout of the Parse iOS SDK is 60 seconds and cannot be customized currently. If you want to make the timeout shorter, you could wrap `PFUser.logInWithUsername` into your own function with your custom timeout.